# Recreate HTTPS request decrypted by Fiddler?

Tags: encryption, https, httprequest, fiddler, winhttprequest

I captured and decrypted an HTTPS request using fiddler. It looks about like this:

```
CONNECT qwer1234.com:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Blabla Example/1.0
Host: qwer1234.com:443
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 13 35 55 0B F2 3C 9D A3 A2 C2 E4 3E 66 FA D3 DD E5 15 27 33 F1 E6 CD A5 E0 C4 10 4E 41 67 32 8E
SessionID: empty
Extensions: 
    renegotiation_info  00
    server_name qwer1234.com
    status_request  01 00 00 00 00
    elliptic_curves secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    signature_algorithms    00 01 06 07 05 08 03 09 04 03 06 04 04 07 01 09
    SessionTicket   empty
Ciphers: 
    [003C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
    [003D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
    [0005]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [C027]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C023]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C024]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C009]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C00A]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0040]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [0032]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA
    [006A]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    [0038]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA
    [0013]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0004]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

Is this a special kind of HTTPS request? Why is only half of the request excrypted? What do the random generated numbers mean / what are they for? How would I send this request using a WinHttpRequest? How does it differ from other HTTPS requests?

I'm kind of bad in finding the right places to ask questions like this. Tell me if you think that I should have asked this on a different page and if so, where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a HTTPS request at all, it is a `CONNECT` tunnel through which HTTPS traffic subsequently flows. Client applications first send a `CONNECT` request to the proxy (like Fiddler) to tell them where to establish a TCP/IP connection to, then after the connection establishes, a HTTPS handshake is performed and the requests are sent.

When showing you the CONNECT tunnel, Fiddler analyzes the parameters and displays them for you to read. The actual HTTPS requests will appear after this tunnel in the Web Sessions list, if and only if you have enabled HTTPS decryption in the Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS screen.